# File location file upload as3

Tags: php, actionscript-3, flash, image-uploading

I'm trying to upload an image with AS3 on my server but I can't find the file on the server after the upload is done.
The php script is called from here:

```
var URLrequest: URLRequest = new URLRequest("uploader_script.php");
```

Both php and swf are located in /test/DJ_2.0/ and the image should go to /test/DJ_2.0/images

The completeHandler function works which makes me think that the upload does work on the AS3 side:

```
fileRef.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, completeHandler);
function completeHandler(event: Event): void {
this.visible = false;
}
```

The php is:

```
$filename = $_FILES['Filedata']['name'];
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['Filedata']['tmp_name'], "images/".$filename);
```

Yet there is no image uploaded in the images folder.

Here is the AS3 upload code:

```
// Function that fires off when File is selected
function syncVariables(event: Event): void {
    fileRef.upload(URLrequest);
    var variables: URLVariables = new URLVariables();
    URLrequest.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;
    URLrequest.data = variables;
}
```

Comment: File permissions on the server grant your script write access to that directory?

Comment: Oooopsss what a mistake of mine! Thanks a bunch for that! Solved!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assure file permissions on the server grant your script write access to that directory.

This appears to have resolved your issue, based upon your [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26962912/file-location-file-upload-as3?noredirect=1#comment42465295_26962912).